# Conditionally Insert in Cosmos DB from azure functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I need to insert data in Cosmos DB from azure functions and below is the working code

```
    [FunctionName("ABC")]
    public static IActionResult Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "deals")] HttpRequest req,
    [CosmosDB(databaseName: "XXX",
                        collectionName: "YYY",
                        ConnectionStringSetting = "OnChangeTrigger_ConnectionString")] out dynamic deal,
    ILogger log)
    {
       string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
        
        deal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(deal.Id?.ToString()))
            {
                deal.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            }
        deal.id = deal.Id;
        return new OkObjectResult(deal.Id.ToString());
     }
```

Is it possible to put some filters (or check data) before inserting?

Comment: what exactly is the issue that you are facing? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to validate my data before inserting to CosmosDB. If validation fails then it should not insert in DB.

Comment: ok, so what is stopping you from implementing that in your code?

Comment: It must be you don't know how to wirte code to implement it, so my question is, which kind of validation you wanna to achieve? Judge vaule is null? Judge if the document contains a specific key? Any else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [AsyncCollector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=csharp#queue-trigger-write-docs-using-iasynccollector):

```
    [FunctionName("ABC")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "deals")] HttpRequest req,
        [CosmosDB(databaseName: "XXX",
                            collectionName: "YYY",
                            ConnectionStringSetting = "OnChangeTrigger_ConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<dynamic> dealsCollector,
        ILogger log)
        {
           string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
            if (someCondition)
            {
                deal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(deal.Id?.ToString()))
                    {
                        deal.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                    }
                deal.id = deal.Id;
                await dealsCollector.AddAsync(deal);
                return new OkObjectResult(deal.Id.ToString());
            }
            
            // return something else?
            return new OkObjectResult();
         }
```